# First time setup webhook. How to subscribe to `message` in the webhook setting?

Tags: facebook, message, webhooks

I would like to have a log chat on my own server by collecting them from the chat history between user and my Facebook page.

I found the document mention about [`message`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages)
[image: message setting]

Next after I can verify my token using `ngrok` get my server connected with Facebook. Then I am looking for `message`.

In my understanding I have to listen to my `page` event. But I could not found and row mentions about it.

I found `message_sends` in the `User`. But it is not what I want.
[image]
[image]

I think document might not get [uptodate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started). In the picture it is `2` and now it is `3`.

Obviously subscription to `User` and select `message_sends` is not a correct solution on my use case. My case is user send message to my page. And my page send webhook to my chatlog server. That's all.

**Question:**
How to connect message on my page to my webhook url?

Answer (score 1):

I have to use `messenger` and then `Subscribe To Events`
[image: messenger]

[image: Found it]